# What's is the right answer: 3-D-printed component vs 3-D printed component vs 3D printed component vs 3D-printed component?

Tags: open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated

Recently, the editors of a journal where I was publishing a paper changed a small part of the title "3d printed components" for "3-D-Printed Components". However, for a different paper, other editors of the same journal wrote "3-D Printed Components" instead.

I have checked on the Internet for other papers that have a similar structure (3D Printed "Sth"), but I don't understand if there is a right way to use the hyphen/s. Here are some examples:

- Compact high-Q hemispherical resonators for 3-D printed bandpass filter applications
- 3-D Printed Flexible Heterogeneous Substrates with Customizable Gain and Bandwidth
- 3D-printed Microsystems for Opto-medical Imaging
- 3-D-Printed Comb Mushroom-Like Dielectric Lens for Stable Gain Enhancement of Printed Log-Periodic Dipole Array

Seems messy in my opinion to use hyphens, however, I would like to know if there's an exact answer, or maybe there are multiple options that are valid.

Thanks,

Comment: This question raises an issue that is **not at all** addressed in the linked question '3D vs 3d vs 3-d vs 3-dimensional', which is alleged to have already answered it. That issue is whether there should be a hyphen **between** *3D* and *printed*. (On a personal note, I have put quite a bit of work into drafting an answer to this question, and I would appreciate it if it were reopened.)